# Request answer good only if i use fiddler python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, fiddler

I work with one project about text ocr

my code on python:

```
import requests

url = "https://translate.yandex.net/ocr/v1.1/recognize?srv=tr-image&sid=&lang=ru&rotate=auto&yu=&yum=&sprvk="
headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Origin": "https://translate.yandex.ru",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Referer": "https://translate.yandex.ru/ocr",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
}

files = {
    'fieldNameHere': ('da.webp', open('da.webp', 'rb'), 'image/webp')
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files,verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

What is wrong - when i just run app without any mitm proxy or sniff apps i get nothing in answer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvx6r.png)

But, when i run fiddler (app to sniff http/https requests) and run code, i get good answer with all data what i need
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/021zy.png)

What it can be?

i try use different headers, but it also without results

Comment: Please don't post text error messages as screenshot. Just include the relevant part as text into your question and format it as code.

Comment: If redirecting traffic through Fiddler changes the result, then the chance is high that the server performs TLS fingerprinting and thus has detected you are using Python, which most likely is not used by any legitimate yandec client. Therefore the server is blocking your request. Redirecting the traffic through Fiddler changes the TLS fingerprint to the one from Windows which is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to suppress the security warning on the `urllib3` level. Also, don't send any `headers=`:

```py
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://translate.yandex.net/ocr/v1.1/recognize?srv=tr-image&sid=&lang=ru&rotate=auto&yu=&yum=&sprvk="

files = {
    "fieldNameHere": ("russian_text.png", open("russian_text.png", "rb"), "image/png")
}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, verify=False)
print(response.json())
```

Prints:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "detected_lang": "ru",
        "rotate": 0,
        "blocks": [
            {
                "angle": 0,
                "x": 0,
                "y": 45,
                "w": 686,
                "h": 42,
                "rx": 0,
                "ry": 44,
                "rw": 686,
                "rh": 47,
                "boxes": [

...
```

---

Image used:

[image]

Comment: i want to get answer, what wrong with requests? Why it shows wrong output, maybe some headers wrong, what was auto-added to post request?

Comment: @YagmiLite You don't need the headers, you set e.g. Connection-Alive that might (or not) mess with the proxy etc. Try to construct the requests with minimum parameters and not just blindly copying them from the browser.